# Issue with WHERE clause on similar data due to "SPACE" difference

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, ascii

**Excel Upload_UI5_SRP** – The space used here between "Excel" and "Upload" is “normal space” which is of ASCII value 32

Whereas

**Excel Upload_UI5_SRP** - The space used here between "Excel" and "Upload" is “non-breakable space(nbsp)” which is of ASCII value 160

[image]

How to resolve this issue?

Is there a solution to convert "non-breakable space(nbsp)" to “normal space” while uploading the data?

Is there a solution to convert "non-breakable space(nbsp)" to “normal space” while fetching the data from the database?

NB: Not expecting solutions like:

```
WHERE CatalogName IN ('Excel Upload_UI5_SRP','Excel Upload_UI5_SRP')
WHERE CatalogName ='Excel Upload_UI5_SRP' OR CatalogName ='Excel Upload_UI5_SRP'
```

Comment: can you just do a `replace()` ?

Comment: Fix the code that insert/updates this table.

Comment: @SMor The insert is a bulk insert. And moreover both the text looks identical, what fix you are suggesting?

Answer (score 2):

A very naive approach might to consider explicitly replacing those characters on input/output via a [`REPLACE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) call:

```
-- Normalize both types of spaces
REPLACE(REPLACE(CatalogName, NCHAR(160), ' '), NCHAR(32), ' ')
```

If you can handle the conversion upstream (i.e. when the data is coming into the database), you should be assured that any queries will work as expected since the data will already have been sanitized.

If you are receiving *both* types of spaces, presumably from user input, you may want to consider writing a custom function that will explicitly handle this scenario and any other potential replacements that you'll need to do in the future (e.g. single quotes, double-quotes, other non-printable characters), such that you could just use something like `Sanitize(@Input)` whenever you would be writing to your database.